# How to resize 4D-image using numpy?

Tags: numpy, image-resizing

I have `(5000, 32, 32, 3)` as `numpy.ndarray`.
(number of images:5000, image size: (32x32), channel: 3)

I want to resize the image (32x32) to (28x28). How can I do this?

Comment: This is way too broad a question for a good answer, but I can point the way [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) and [here](https://sighack.com/post/averaging-rgb-colors-the-right-way).  And for the future, please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`scipy.ndimage.zoom()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html).

Something like:

```
import scipy.ndimage

factor = 28.0 / 32.0
scipy.ndimage.zoom(input_array, (1, factor, factor, 1))
```

Comment: Do note that zoom is "lazy" when downsampling, not properly averaging over pixels and hence losing some information.

Comment: Sure, running a uniform (or other) filter prior to to `zoom` would indeed be a good idea.